# How to create doubleTwist Alarm Clock circular/round seekbar?

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I’ve research a few circular seekbar solutions, but none of them can design a beautiful circular seekbar like doubleTwist.

[image]

Any Android UI expert knows how to design this?

Comment: Have you investigated extending an exiting seekbar View and overriding the `onDraw` method to draw it as a circle?

Comment: Yes, it will be like either of these solutions, but the doubleTwist designs is different. (http://www.androidviews.net/2013/03/holo-circular-progressbar/ , https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar)

Comment: Well, why not start with one of those and modify it? It looks like you would simply need to take the second one and update the `onDraw` method to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try forking and extending this library,

https://github.com/tripadvisor/android-clockseekbar